# Can't delete git credentials

Tags: git, github

When I use git pull, I've got error message:

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/CheckmarxDev/repostore.git/'
```

I deleted credentials from the windows credential manager. Reinstalled Git. And made another thing, but I always get this error. Where git cash his data, and how I can clear all information of credential?

I want, that when I used "git pull" - I again get a message, where I need to enter login and password. As first time. How to restore git to his basic empty configuration?

Comment: Have you restarted windows?

Comment: Yes, restarted.

Answer (score 1):

The [Git FAQ has an entry on how to reset the credentials in your credential manager](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-reset-credentials):

```
$ echo url=https://github.com | git credential reject
```

Note that if you are using the legacy `manager` credential helper, then this may not work due to a bug.  You can try doing this to work around it, which may or may not work (replace `username` with your username):

```
$ echo url=https://username@github.com | git credential reject
```

You can also update Git for Windows to the latest version and use the `manager-core` credential helper, which should work properly.

The place that Git stores this information depends on the credential manager in question, which is responsible for this decision.